# upload and display image from absolute directory with tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I successfully upload picture on absolute path

Here is my context in server.xml

```
<Context docBase="/opt/images" path="/images" reloadable="true"/>
```

But when i try to open it `"http://domain/Project/images/newUploadedPicture.jpg"`, 404 File not found appear. When I restart tomcat server I can access that image.

Any solution?

Comment: I hope that your upload page is suitably protected or your Tomcat server will be wide open to attack by a malicious user.

Comment: If you wait a short while after the upload (say a minute) does the file appear?

Comment: I tried after 5 minutes and still same.
This happens only on dedicated server. Works fine on localhost

Comment: There are several configuration options that could trigger this behaviour. Look at the Context configuration for the anti-resource locking settings.

Comment: I set following options : antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true". But I still have the same problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Based on that config, I'd expect the image to appear at http://domain/images/newUploadedPicture.jpg

Comment: No, still doesn't work. on localhost i'm working on windows machine and the server where doesn't work is linux...can that be cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try http//yourdomain/images/yourImage.jpg